Expected value of number of unique integers in a sequence of $n$ integers selected from $[1,n]$
Let $f(n)$ be the expected value of the number of unique integers in a sequence of $n$ integers selected uniformly randomly from $[1,n]$. Find the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{n}.$$
The answer is $1-e^{-1}$, but I'm not sure how to reach it.

Inclusions/exclusions?

We can calculate $f(n)$ using Linearity of Expectation. Let $X_n$ be the random variable where $f(n)=\mathbb{E}[X_n]$. We have that
$$X_n=X_{1n}+X_{2n}+\cdots+X_{nn},$$
where $X_{jn}$ is the random variable that is $1$ when $j$ is one of the $n$ integers we select and $0$ otherwise. Then $\mathbb{E}[X_{jn}]$ is the probability $j$ is in our list. This is just $1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$ by complementary probability. Hence by linearity of expectation
$$f(n)=\mathbb{E}[X_n]=n\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right).$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n}=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=1-e^{-1}.$$
